# counter with specific condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I am have issue in conditional increment for the below input.

condition:
In my expected input 5 will be repeated. I want to add versioning to  element if it is  repeated and only if it has value equal to 5

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?> <data> <rec>
    <Pt>1</Pt>
  </rec>
  <rec>
    <Pt>3</Pt>
  </rec>
  <rec>
    <Pt>5</Pt>
  </rec>
  <rec>
    <Pt>5</Pt>
  </rec>
  <rec>
    <Pt>5</Pt>
  </rec>
  <rec>
    <Pt>6</Pt>
  </rec>
</data>
```

Output expected :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record>
    <PT>1</PT>
    <DerivedPT>1</DerivedPT>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PT>3</PT>
    <DerivedPT>3</DerivedPT>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PT>5</PT>
    <DerivedPT>5.1</DerivedPT>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PT>5</PT>
    <DerivedPT>5.2</DerivedPT>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PT>5</PT>
    <DerivedPT>5.3</DerivedPT>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PT>6</PT>
    <DerivedPT>6</DerivedPT>
</Record>
```

I have tried this XSLT :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="data/rec">
            <Record>
                <PT>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Pt" />
                </PT>
                <DerivedPT>
                    <xsl:variable name="pt" select="Pt" />
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($pt,'5')">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="concat($pt,'.',count(preceding-sibling::rec/Pt[1])+1)" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$pt" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </DerivedPT>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, output i am getting is :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record>
    <PT>1</PT>
    <DerivedPT>1</DerivedPT>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PT>3</PT>
    <DerivedPT>3</DerivedPT>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PT>5</PT>
    <DerivedPT>5.3</DerivedPT>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PT>5</PT>
    <DerivedPT>5.4</DerivedPT>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PT>5</PT>
    <DerivedPT>5.5</DerivedPT>
</Record>
<Record>
    <PT>6</PT>
    <DerivedPT>6</DerivedPT>
</Record>
```

This is because it is picking all the  tags.What changes i have to make so it will take only PT which is 5.

```
                        <xsl:value-of
                            select="concat($pt,'.',count(preceding-sibling::rec/Pt[1])+1)" />
```

Comment: Do you really want to add the numbering if "5" is repeated? That is to say, if "3" was repeated, would you also want numbering on that? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC .No. In my case only 5 will be repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the subversion number within a variable for better readability, but the following worked well for your requirements. Replace the contents of your `<xsl:choose>` with the following:

```
<xsl:when test="contains($pt,'5')">
  <xsl:variable name="thisSubversion" select="count(preceding-sibling::rec[Pt='5']) + 1" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($pt,'.', $thisSubversion)" />
</xsl:when>
```

This allows you to look at only the value of `rec/Pt` nodes that have a value of "5". I hope this helps!

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38Zz

Answer (score 1):

Although it may be only 5 that is repeated, this might be an opportunity to make use a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) as it is a good technique to learn (assuming you are restricted to XSLT 1.0)

In this case, you can re-write your XSLT as this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="recs" match="rec" use="Pt" />

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="rec[generate-id() = generate-id(key('recs', Pt)[1])]">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('recs', Pt)" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rec">
    <Record>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Pt" />
      <DerivedPT>
        <xsl:value-of select="Pt" />
        <xsl:if test="Pt = '5'">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('.',position())" />
        </xsl:if>
      </DerivedPT>
    </Record>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The advantage here is that if you did want all records to have the logic, not just "5", then you just remove the `xsl:if` condition.

And, if you have a large structure, this should be more efficient that constantly counting the number of preceding siblings.

Answer (score 1):

I too would prefer to avoid the repeated counting backwards and do something like this instead:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="rec">
    <Record>
        <PT>
            <xsl:value-of select="Pt" />
        </PT>
        <DerivedPT>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Pt=5">
                    <xsl:text>5.</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:number count="rec[Pt=5]"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Pt" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </DerivedPT>
    </Record>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```